# Python adding values from multiple columns to a set()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, set, unique

I am having trouble combining multiple values from 10 columns into one `set`. I wanted to use a set because each column has repeated values and I am looking to get a list of all of the values (medical codes) without repeating any of them in the list. I was able to make an initial set out of the first column but when I try to add other columns I get an "unhashable type error".

Here is my code:

```
data_sorted = data.fillna(0).sort_values(['PAT_ID', 'VISIT_NO'])
set_ICD1 = set(data_sorted['ICD_1'].unique())
print(len(set_ICD1))
set_ICD = set_ICD1.add(data_sorted['ICD_2'])

print(len(set_ICD))
```

here is the error I get with this:

```
11586 # (not part of the error this is the length of the initial set)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e3966ec54661> in <module>()
  1 set_ICD1 = set(data_sorted['ICD_1'].unique())
  2 print(len(set_ICD1))
----> 3 set_ICD = set_ICD1.add(data_sorted['ICD_2'].unique())
  4 
  5 print(len(set_ICD))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Any advice or tips how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error is exactly what it means. Arrays are not hashable, they're mutable too which precludes hashing. You need another container, or use `update()` if you wish to add items from the container.

Comment: It's happening because you are trying to add the entire column as a numpy.ndarray. try looping over that array, and adding elements individually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add multiple elements to a `set` at once you need to use the [`update`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update) method instead of [`add`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.add):

```
set_ICD1.update(data_sorted['ICD_2'])
```

In case it's a NumPy array you should probably use `ravel()` (in case it's n-dimensional - this will flatten it) and `tolist()` (for performance):

```
set_ICD1.update(data_sorted['ICD_2'].ravel().tolist())
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am getting this error when I try to print the length of the new set using `print(len(set_ICD))` `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-5cfdc9801acb> in <module>()
----> 1 print(len(set_ICD))

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

Comment: My mistake. Fixed  now.